32-bit ALU testbench trouble-shoot
I am writing a testbench for a 32-bit ALU.
I am getting a u on the ovrflow and co outputs.
Here is the design file:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity alu_32bit is
--  Port ( );

GENERIC(N: integer:= 32);
 Port ( A : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
 B : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
 ALUOp : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
 RESULT : out std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
 ovrflow: out std_logic;
 co : out std_logic;
 zero : out std_logic);

end alu_32bit;

architecture Behavioral of alu_32bit is

signal co2ci :std_logic_vector(N-2 downto 0);
signal setN20 : std_logic;
signal res :std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0):=(others=>'0');

component alu_1bit
 Port ( a : in std_logic;
 b : in std_logic;
 ci : in std_logic;
 less : in std_logic;
 binvert : in std_logic;
 Op : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
 co : out std_logic;
 result : out std_logic);
end component;
component alu_1bit_msb
port( a : In std_logic;
b : In std_logic;
ci : In std_logic;
less : In std_logic;
binvert : In std_logic;
Op : In std_logic_vector (1 DownTo 0);
Ovrflow : out std_logic;
set : out std_logic;
co : out std_logic;
result : out std_logic);
end component;



begin

alu0 : alu_1bit port map( A(0),
B(0),
ALUOp(2),
setN20,
ALUOp(2),
ALUOp(1 downto 0),
co2ci(0),
res(0));

g1: for i in 1 to N-2 generate

alu : alu_1bit port map( A(i),
B(i),
co2ci(i-1),
'0',
ALUOp(2),
ALUOp(1 downto 0),
co2ci(i),
res(i));
end generate;

aluN : alu_1bit_msb port map( A(N-1),
B(N-1),
co2ci(N-2),
'0',
ALUOp(2),
ALUOp(1 downto 0),
ovrflow,
setN20,
co,
res(N-1));
RESULT<=res;
zero <= '1' when res=X"00000000" else '0';
    
end Behavioral;

Here is what is have of the testbench so far:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity alu_32bit_test is
--  Port ( );
end alu_32bit_test;

architecture Behavioral of alu_32bit_test is
-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)
 COMPONENT alu_32bit
 PORT(
 A : IN std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 B : IN std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 ALUOp : IN std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
 RESULT : OUT std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 ovrflow : OUT std_logic;
 co : OUT std_logic;
 zero : OUT std_logic
 );
 END COMPONENT;
 --Inputs
 signal A : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => 
'0');
 signal B : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => 
'0');
 signal ALUOp : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => 
'0');
--Outputs
 signal RESULT : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 signal ovrflow : std_logic;
 signal co : std_logic;
 signal zero : std_logic;
 -- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below 
--with 
 -- appropriate port name 
 --constant <clock>_period : time := 10 ns;
BEGIN
-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
 uut: alu_32bit PORT MAP (
 A => A,
 B => B,
 ALUOp => ALUOp,
 RESULT => RESULT,
 ovrflow => ovrflow,
 co => co,
 zero => zero
 );
 -- Clock process definitions
--stimulus process
 stim_proc: process
 begin
 
    wait for 10 ns;
   --or?
    ALUOP<="001";
   -- 269488152
    A<=X"10101018";
    --4311810313
    B<=X"01010109";
   
    wait for 10 ns;
   --add
    ALUOP<="010";
   
    A<=X"10101018";
    B<=X"71010109";
   
    wait for 10 ns;
    --subtract
    
    ALUOP<="110";
    --2952790016
    A<=X"B0000000";
    --2147483647
    B<=X"7fffffff";
   
    wait for 10 ns;
    --set on less than
    
    ALUOP<="111";
   
    A<=X"B0000000";
    B<=X"7fffffff";
   
    wait for 10 ns;
    wait;
 end process;
END;


If I am understanding the code correctly, it is populating the 32 bit alu's and performing the different operations on the populated inputs? I don't understand why I am getting the U for the output though.
Here is an image of the output:


The code for the instantiated components must be provided for analysis.

The question should not be closed for lack of details.  The question is clear, and the answer shows how to fix it.

There are many warnings when I run a simulation on EDA Playground, on several simulators.  For example:
    Warning-[ELW_UNBOUND] Unbound component
      The component instantiation '/ALU_32BIT_TEST/UUT/G1(30)/ALU' (file: 
      /home/runner/design.vhd, line: 72) will have no effect because component 
      'ALU_1BIT' is unbound. No entity definition for component 'ALU_1BIT' can be 
      found in the following libraries (  WORK  ) referenced by the architecture 
      'BEHAVIORAL' of entity 'ALU_32BIT'.
      Please bind the component explicitly to an entity (architecture) pair, and 
      verify that the pair was analyzed successfully.

You need to pay attention to warning messages because they often notify you of bugs in your code.  If your simulator did not show warnings, then consider using other simulators such as those on EDA Playground.

That's not surprising when the entity/architectures for alu_1bit and alu_1bit_msb are not provided in the question. You're not provided enough information to replicate the issue. It's not illegal to have unbound components,
